# How do I automap a component collection in Fluent NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, components, automapping

I have a `TrackLog` that contains a collection of GPS points as a `TrackPoint` object:

```
public class TrackPoint
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<TrackPoint> TrackPoints { get;set; }
}

public class TrackLog
{
    public virtual double Latitude { get; set; }
    public virtual double Longitude { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

`TrackPoint` is a component and I've created an `IAutomappingConfiguration` that tells FNH to map it as such. However, when I try to run my program, FNH spits out the following exception:

> Association references unmapped class: TestProject.Components.TrackPoint

How do I map a collection of components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my problem. Rafael, in response to your question, `TrackLog` has a collection of `TrackPoints`. Normally in this case, `TrackPoint` would be an entity, but because a `TrackPoint` should not exist if it doesn't belong in a `TrackLog`, I decided to make it a component, which ties its lifetime to its parent `TrackLog`.

It turns out the problem I was having was that, even though I created an automapping override, it wasn't working:

```
internal class TrackLogOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<TrackLog>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<TrackLog> mapping)
    {
        mapping.HasMany(x => x.TrackPoints).Component(x =>
            {
                x.Map(m => m.Latitude);
                x.Map(m => m.Longitude);
                x.Map(m => m.Timestamp);
            });
    }
}
```

Turns out that I needed to make the override class `public` for FNH to use them because I was using FNH in another assembly.

Answer (score 0):

The very **first** thing that needs to change is to change the `List` type to `IList`. The reason for needs is because NHibernate needs to inject its own type of collection, not C#'s own `List`.

What I don't understand is TrackPoint per se. You're saying that it's a component consuming itself? Could you give us more insight? I'm confused.

Say I have a class Track which consumes TrackPoint as a component:

```
public class TrackMap : ClassMap<TrackPoint>
{
 Id(x => x.Id);

 Component(x => x.TrackPoint, m =>
 {
      m.Map(x => x.Id);

         // Try one of the following (not sure):
         m.Map(x => x.TrackPoints);
         m.HasMany(x => x.TrackPoints);
 } 
}
```

Does this help?